# mac terminal alias set up password

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to create alias to reboot computer. Tried to set alias reboot='sudo reboot'. But it required to enter password. I want to know is that possible to put the password into this alias.

Comment: If you want to run specific commands as a superuser, you should look into configuring `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not put the password in the alias. `sudo` prevents this because it's a huge security hole.

Instead, run `sudo visudo` and add the line

```
yourusernamehere ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

then your current alias will stop asking for a password and just allow the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an alias like this
   alias odo2='echo ROOT_PASSWD | sudo -S reboot'
2. Even better put all your aliases inside
   ~/.bash_profile
   [This #2 would work if your have not changed your terminal login preferences to a different shell... Most probably your login shell would load up bash]